# Powershell find/delete duplicate outlook contacts

Tags: powershell, outlook

So I have this script I've been using to find/delete duplicate Outlook contacts. I have had success with this script, however, recently started getting errors. I'm no Powershell expert, nor do I claim to be proficient with it, so I'm stumbling my way through this. Just looking for some input, or ideas, as to why this bombs-out at ...getting unique items

The script

```
#########################################################
#                                                       #
#    Remove Duplicate Outlook Contacts by Jean Louw     #
#    Blog http://powershellneedfulthings.blogspot.com/  #
#                                                       #
#########################################################

$olSession = (New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application).Session
$olSession.Logon('Outlook') #Outlook is the profile name
$contactsFolder = 10
$tempFolderName = 'temp_folder_' + (get-date -Format ddmmyyyhhmmss)
$myContacts = $olSession.GetDefaultFolder($contactsFolder).Items
$tempFolder = $olSession.GetDefaultFolder($contactsFolder).Folders.Add($tempFolderName)

Write-Host "..getting unique items"
$uniqueContacts = $myContacts | Sort FullName -Unique

#move contacts to temp contacts folder
foreach ($Contact in $uniqueContacts) {
$Contact.Move($tempFolder) | foreach-object {Write-Progress "Backup unique items to temp folder..." $_.FullName; $_.FullName} | Out-Null}

#read default contacts again and dump to csv
Write-Host "..export duplicates to csv"
$duplicates = $olSession.GetDefaultFolder($contactsFolder).Items
$duplicates | Export-Csv duplicates.csv

#delete all contacts left in default contacts folder
Foreach ($duplicate in $duplicates){
$duplicate.Delete() | foreach-object {Write-Progress "Deleting duplicate..." $_.FullName; $_.FullName} | Out-Null}
```

The output

```
    Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\system32> $olSession = (New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application).Session
PS C:\Windows\system32> $olSession.Logon('Outlook') #Outlook is the profile name
PS C:\Windows\system32> $contactsFolder = 10
PS C:\Windows\system32> $tempFolderName = 'temp_folder_' + (get-date -Format ddmmyyyhhmmss)
PS C:\Windows\system32> $myContacts = $olSession.GetDefaultFolder($contactsFolder).Items
PS C:\Windows\system32> $tempFolder = $olSession.GetDefaultFolder($contactsFolder).Folders.Add($tempFolderName)
PS C:\Windows\system32> Write-Host "..getting unique items"
..getting unique items
PS C:\Windows\system32> $uniqueContacts = $myContacts | Sort FullName -Unique
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8837000E.
At line:1 char:18
+ $uniqueContacts = <<<<  $myContacts | Sort FullName -Unique
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation (System.Runtime....ewOfEnumVariant:EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

source of this script http://www.powershellneedfulthings.com/?p=35

Comment: I have verified that the Profile name is Outlook

Comment: It's odd that the error is for the line it is but says line 1. What is the results of `$myContacts` without the pipe when it errors? Does it work on some computer and not others or is this on your computer that this issue happens?

Comment: This works on my own computer, I created 12 duplicates of one of my own contacts and tried it, worked flawlessly. I will try $myContacts without the pipe and see what happens.

Comment: $myContacts returns nothing ... so I retried this script yesterday and came back to this new output.

Comment: Put on Pastebin for easier reading. [link](http://pastebin.com/pJAspjEg)

Comment: So Saturday afternoon, I spend a few hours manually selecting the duplicate contacts, so to delete them. Well I started the delete process and walked away for a few hours. Come back to find Outlook crashed, so I restarted Outlook, and it would not run without crashing no matter what I did. Ended up renaming the OST and recreating it.

Comment: The only way I got this script to run without failing was to manually delete the duplicates so that I was only working with 20 some thousand contacts. I don't know exactly how long it took, but I started running it, then walked away for two hours, came back and it had successfully completed, doing exactly what it was supposed to do. Might have been the system I was working with, a Panasonic Toughbook CF31, Core i5 2520M 2.5 GHz, 4GB system memory, Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Comment: Just for full disclosure, this is what caused my issue in the first place. I'm merely placing this info by chance it helps someone out in the future. http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/248008-android-duplicating-contacts